# Flexbox order and wrap 3 items

Tags: css, flexbox

This is what I'm trying to do:

Up to 768px (left) and over (right):

[image]

Right now my code looks like this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  > * {
    width: 50%;
  }
  &__name {
    order: 0;
  }
  &__desc {
    order: 2;
  }
  &__link {
    order: 1;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    > * {
      width: 100%;
    }
    &__name {
      order: 0;
    }
    &__desc {
      order: 1;
    }
    &__link {
      order: 2;
    }
  }
}
```

But that makes it look like this:

[image]

What am I missing to make the items wrap this way? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This is only possible with a known height of the wrapper. It needs to know *when* to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  >* {
    width: 50%;
  }
  &__name {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 0 0 0;
    order: 0;
  }
  &__desc {
    background-color: pink;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    order: 2;
    height: 100%;
  }
  &__link {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 0 0 0;
    order: 1;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    >* {
      width: 100%;
    }
    &__name {
      order: 0;
    }
    &__desc {
      order: 1;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      height: auto;
    }
    &__link {
      order: 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7x0ptam/18/), hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: isn't it what you want  to achieve?